# Angular 2+ change Transclusion/content projection at runtime

Tags: angular, transclusion

I am trying to create a control which allows the declaration of a set of content objects wrapped in specific formatting. This is easy in and of itself, but I also want to show those objects in exactly one of 2 different locations depending on user input. The intention is it would never appear in both or neither of those locations.

I have been trying to use the transclusion/content projection functionality of Angular as this seems like it does exactly what I want, but I can't get it to update based on user actions. I have set up 2 ng-content elements with different css class selectors, but once the controls have been placed they do not move if the class changes.

Is there a way to re-run/update the transclusion of an object when the assigned classes change?

I have created a basic reproduction of the problem here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3x41ta

(the intent of the example would be that clicking the "move" button causes the corresponding item to appear in the other section)

Comment: You need one level more. Why don't you manage your 2 sections as 2 lists (with ngFor) ? Transclusion need fixed classes but you can totally manipulate its content. `<div class="section1"><app-content *ngFor="..."></app-content></div>`

Comment: @Gilsdav how do I marshal and filter the content into those 2 ngFor loops? I am emitting some buttons using an ngFor but I can't see how I can use that to emit the actual components, and that seems like exactly what transclusion *should* be doing for me? Is there a feature or functionality that I'm just not aware of to handle this?